# Plotly dropdown selection not updating the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, plotly, visualization

I'm using a dropdown menu to select a column and update the plotly graph based on the selected column. This is my code to do the same.

```
def update_plot(column):
   value_counts = df[column].value_counts()
   fig = px.bar(x=value_counts.index, y=value_counts.values, labels={'x': column, 'y': 'Count'},
                title=f'Value Counts of {column}')
   fig.show()

column_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=df[object_columns].columns, description='Select Column:')
# Display the widget
display(column_dropdown)

# Create the initial plot based on the first column in the DataFrame
initial_column = df[object_columns].columns[0]
update_plot(initial_column)

# Set up the callback to update the plot when the dropdown selection changes
column_dropdown.observe(lambda change: update_plot(change.new), names='value')
```

This code only shows the plot for the first column. When I change the column using the dropdown menu, the plot remains unchanged. I have looked for solutions online, but nothing seems to work. Could someone help me with this please?